# Adding multiple entries/rows with knex mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, knex.js

I get the following data from the `req.body`:

```
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "user_name": "jkalandarov",
    "email": "jkalandarov@gmail.com",
    "courses": [
        {
            "course_id": 1,
            "course_name": "English",
            "course_price": 265
        },
        {
            "course_id": 2,
            "course_name": "Node.js",
            "course_price": 200
        },
        {
            "course_id": 3,
            "course_name": "Backend Developement",
            "course_price": 300
        }        
    ]
}
```

I want to insert this data into three rows with the help of knex into mysql database table like this with a single query:
[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have your knex connection set up, it should simply allow you to pass an array of objects into the `insert` function to insert multiple rows with a single statement. https://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert

Step 1: Build an array of objects

```js
const objectsToInsert = req.body.courses.map(course => {
    return {
        user_id: req.body.user_id,
        user_name: req.body.user_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        ...course
    }
});
```

Step 2: Insert them using your knex connection

```
await knex('your_table_name').insert(objectsToInsert);
```

This should insert those three rows into your table in a single query.

As this data is coming directly from the request body it is obviously also a good idea to add some validation here but that feels out of scope for your original question.